# Using jQuery to validate value in comparison to other input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a base Hour input field and I'm trying to validate the other input fields so that once the base hour is added the other input values can only be as large as the first base rate Hours column (first input). Or put another way the one input field becomes the max number value once it is entered. So if the base is 12 for the Hours column the second and third rate can be no larger than 12. The tricky part is add new row feature means all new rows for the hour column have to adhere to the rule as well. I have been trying to figure it out for a bit, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuzhuom9/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#calculate').on('click', function() {
    $('.hours-table tr').each(function() {
        var hours = $(this).find('input.hours').val();
        var rate = $(this).find('input.rate').val();
        var dateTotal = (hours * rate);
        $(this).find('input.date-total').val(dateTotal);

      // total += parseInt($("input.date-total").val());

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("input.date-total").each(function () {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);

            }


        }); 

            if (sum < 0) {
                alert("Total can't be negative");
                $('#grandtotal-new').val('');
            } else {
        $("#grandtotal-new").val(sum)
        }

    }); //END .each
    return false;

}); // END click 

});

$(function(){
var counter = 4;
$('a.add-row').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" class="hours" name="rate-0' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-0' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="date-total" readonly name="date-total-0' + counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    $('table.hours-table').append(newRow);
});
});
</script>
```

The html is:

```
<table class="hours-table">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Hourly Rate</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Base Rate:</td>
    <td class="hours"><input type="number" class="hours" id="base-hours" name="hours-01" max="???" min="???" value="" /></td>
    <td class="rate"><input min="0" class="rate" name="rate-01" value="200" readonly /></td>
    <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="date-total-0" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second Rate:</td>
    <td class="hours"><input type="number" class="hours" name="hours-02" max="???" min="???" value="" /></td>
    <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-02" value="-20" readonly /></td>
    <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="date-total-1" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Third Rate:</td>
    <td class="hours"><input type="number" class="hours" name="hours-03" max="???" min="???" value="" /></td>
    <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-03" value="10" readonly /></td>
    <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="date-total-2" readonly/></td>
</tr>


</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-row">Add New Rule</a><br />
<button type="button" id='calculate' class="btn btn-inverse btn-  mini">Calculate</button>
The Grand total is: <input type="number" id='grandtotal-new' min="???"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just validate them on `blur` of each `.hours` input as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuzhuom9/3/)**

```
$(document).on('blur','.hours',function(){
    var current=$(this);
    if(!(current).is('input.hours:first'))
    {
        if(current.val()>$('input.hours:first').val())
            current.val('');
    }
});
```

> This will check value of `input` on `blur` and clears it if it is greater than first one

**UPDATE:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuzhuom9/9/)**
`parse` the value before checking as below:

```
$(document).on('blur','.hours',function(){
    var current=$(this);
    if(!(current).is('input.hours:first'))
    {
        if(parseInt(current.val())>parseInt($('input.hours:first').val()))
            current.val('');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on OPs comments here is the way to achieve the requirements mentioned by him.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuzhuom9/12/)**

```
$(document).on('blur','.hours',function(e){
    var current=$(this);
    var base=$('input.hours:first');
    var total=0;
    var other=$('input.hours:not(:first)');
    if(base.val()==="")
    {
        alert('Enter Base First');
        current.val('');
        base.focus();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    $.each($(other),function(index,value){
        if(value.value!=="")
               total+=parseInt(parseInt(value.value)); 
    });
    console.log(total);
    if(!(current).is(base))
    {
        if(parseInt(current.val())>parseInt(base.val()))
        {
            current.val('');
        }
        else if(total>parseInt($('input.hours:first').val()))
            current.val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is definitely a step in the right direction. One thing though is that the second field , third field, etc take certain numbers but reject others. Try 10 for base hour and a 4 for Second Rate. It clears the current value even though it is less than the first input.

Comment: @user3461371 Do not forget to mark it as answer if it helped you and also to help others in future whenever anyone visits this question

Comment: Marked as answered. You know your jQuery.  One last question. How would you go about making sure the other rates are less than or equal to the first rate summed together? So they all add up to the base rate Hours.

Comment: You mean Other rates entered should be less than base rate in total? and when you want to check this condition?

Comment: Yes. So the other rates are less than the base rate and in total and checked on blur.

Comment: Cool and you want to clear all the value right if total gets greater?

Comment: Exactly. Or clear the value of the one last input that is breaking logic.

Comment: and what you want to do if he enters others first and base last??

Comment: Good point. Alert base needs to be as big or put the sum of others into base if put in last. Or clear other input. Whichever is easier.

Comment: @user3461371 Updated answer!! Check and let me knw!!

Comment: Learning so much. Only thing I can see is it allows you to go over total if you add a couple rows after inputing base.

Comment: @user3461371 Updated answer and demo!! I should have checked for null values before adding it to total!! Check the last demo and update!!

Comment: binding the other inputs to the base input instead of waiting for a blur event is better i would think.

Comment: Can you bit elaborate it please!!

Answer (score 0):

add this at the beginning of your jquery script.
this will limit the other hours input to whatever is on base-hours, including newly added rows.

```
var baseRate =  0;

$(".hours-table").on("input","input.hours",function() {
   if ($(this).attr('id') == 'base-hours'){
      baseRate = $(this).val();
   }else if ($(this).val() > baseRate){
      $(this).val(baseRate);   
   }
});
```

and then further down below you have  a syntax/logic error on your add row function. replace this line with this corrected line, and you might wanna move your counter++ after this line.

```
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" class="hours" name="rate-0' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate-0' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="date-total" readonly name="date-total-0' + counter + '"/></td></tr>');
```

check this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uuzhuom9/8/